# Mod Rewrite Htaccess for Fake Directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create fake directories to redirect specific parameters to specific subdirectories as such:

```
From: www.example.com/username
  To: www.example.com/posts?uid=alex

From: www.example.com/p/1234
  To: www.example.com/posts?url=1234
```

It is somehow more complicated example from the rest questions with the same subject on stackoverflow and most answers do not give an explanation on how it works, thus I am not able to come into a conclusion on how I could solve this.

Comment: You're actually looking for `Front Controller` (which includes routing and dispatching).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^p/([^/]+)$ /posts?url=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /posts?uid=$1 [L]
```

First, you need to make all of your links look like this:

```
www.example.com/username
www.example.com/p/1234
```

The rewrite rules above will match the `/p/1234` (via `^p/([^/]+)$`) and `/username` (via `^([^/]+)$`) and internally rewrite them to the `/posts` URI. Note that this will *not* change the URL in the browser's location bar, as that is an external redirect. If someone enters `www.example.com/posts?uid=alex`, the URL will be unchanged.

Comment: Ah it doesn't seems to work because on the my actual file posts.php I get the parameter with javascript and send it to the api as such: http://pastebin.com/CckMbbrg which doesn't logs anything.

Comment: @ATs if you get parameters with javascript, then just do all of the fake directory stuff using javascript, you don't need mod-rewrite at all

Comment: ah how can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^p/([^/]+)/?$ /posts?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /posts?uid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```